# Independence in Banach space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Everyone knows one of the basic theorems in linear algebra: $k+1$ vectors can't be linear independent in the span of $k$ vectors. Also, it's pretty easy to prove that there is no uncountable system of independent vectors in the span of the countable system. 
Now, let's take it up a notch. 
Suppose we have a Banach space and a countable set of vectors $\{v_i\}$, such that every vector from the space is the sum of series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kv_k$ and no vector in $\{v_i\}$ is the sum of series of other vectors. So, it's similar to Hilbert basis. The main question is: can there be an uncountable set of vectors such that no vector can be written as a sum of series of other? The second question is: what conditions we have to add/remove to change the answer?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You need to differentiate between linear independence, which only cares about finite summation; and allowing infinite summations, which require the notion of a topology (which of course we have in Banach spaces).

Comment: A trivial example: take $\ell_1(\Bbb R)$ and the standard unit vectors $\{e_\alpha:\alpha\in\Bbb R\}$. I'm not sure what happens in the separable case; but I'll think about it.